# WIF: "The signing token Generic XML token ... has no keys"

Tags: office365, wif, adfs

For a customer I am trying to get a token from MicrosoftOnline (office 365) using ADFS OnPrem. In short:

1. Request a token from OnPrem STS (Adfs)
2. Send the received token to the Federated STS (MicrosoftOnline)

Now, I do have working code that sends hardcoded soap messages to ADFS & MicrosoftOnline. I am trying to refactor this code to use WIF, but I’m having a hard time getting step 2 to work. I can manage step 1 fine, but when I try to call MicrosoftOnline I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The signing token Generic XML token:
>
> validFrom: 09/30/2015 13:25:40
>
> validTo: 09/30/2015 14:25:40
>
> InternalTokenReference:
>   SamlAssertionKeyIdentifierClause(AssertionId =
>   '_622096af-9cb5-4b19-b69d-5d60639c16e3')
>
> ExternalTokenReference:
>   SamlAssertionKeyIdentifierClause(AssertionId =
>   '_622096af-9cb5-4b19-b69d-5d60639c16e3')
>
> Token Element: (Assertion, urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion)
>
> has no keys. The security token is used in a context that requires it
>   to perform cryptographic operations, but the token contains no
>   cryptographic keys. Either the token type does not support
>   cryptographic operations, or the particular token instance does not
>   contain cryptographic keys. Check your configuration to ensure that
>   cryptographically disabled token types (for example,
>   UserNameSecurityToken) are not specified in a context that requires
>   cryptographic operations (for example, an endorsing supporting token).

Here is the code I have so far. The error is thrown when calling **channel.issue**.

```
public static SecurityToken GetRSTSToken(SecurityToken idpToken)
{
    var binding = new IssuedTokenWSTrustBinding2();
    binding.SecurityMode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;

    var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
        binding,
        "https://login.microsoftonline.com/RST2.srf");
    factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
    factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
    factory.Credentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = true;

    var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
    {
        RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
        AppliesTo = new EndpointReference("urn:crmemea:dynamics.com"),
    };

    var channel = factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(idpToken);
    SecurityToken returnValue = channel.Issue(rst);
    return returnValue;
}
```

The call to **GetRSTSToken** is preceded by a call to the method **GetToken**. The output from **GetToken** is passed to **GetRSTSToken**. I used Fiddler to check the soap messages and they are almost identical to the soap messages I send in my current - working - code. The only thing that is different are the fields you would expect (id's, timestamps, etc).

```
public static SecurityToken GetToken(string username, string password)
{
    // Windows authentication over transport security
    var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
        new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
        "https://sts.windesheim.nl/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed");
    factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
    factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = username;
    factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;
    factory.Credentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = true;

    var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
    {
        RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
        AppliesTo = new EndpointReference("urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline"),
        KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer
    };

    var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
    SecurityToken returnValue = channel.Issue(rst);
    return returnValue;
}
```

NOTE: UserNameWSTrustBinding and IssuedTokenWSTrustBinding are from Thinktecture.IdentityModel (https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45)

For reference, here are the -working- soap messages:

1. To OnPrem STS

Soap Request

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:755c37dd-eee4-4e7e-a9e0-be3c6289b46a</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">[sts_url]</a:To>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2015-06-10T08:21:44.804Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2015-06-10T08:26:44.804Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-3e6d680b-4cb1-4c38-aff8-93c8fa8bd0c6-1">
                <o:Username>[username]</o:Username>
                <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">[password]</o:Password>
            </o:UsernameToken>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <trust:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
            <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
                <a:EndpointReference>
                    <a:Address>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</a:Address>
                </a:EndpointReference>
            </wsp:AppliesTo>
            <trust:KeyType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
            <trust:RequestType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue</trust:RequestType>
        </trust:RequestSecurityToken>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Soap Response

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RSTRC/IssueFinal</a:Action>
        <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:755c37dd-eee4-4e7e-a9e0-be3c6289b46a</a:RelatesTo>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2015-06-10T08:21:45.097Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2015-06-10T08:26:45.097Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
            <trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
                <trust:Lifetime>
                    <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2015-06-10T08:21:45.082Z</wsu:Created>
                    <wsu:Expires xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2015-06-10T09:21:45.082Z</wsu:Expires>
                </trust:Lifetime>
                <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
                    <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                        <wsa:Address>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</wsa:Address>
                    </wsa:EndpointReference>
                </wsp:AppliesTo>
                <trust:RequestedSecurityToken>
                    <saml:Assertion MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" AssertionID="_68133973-ed12-49d7-9f43-421bcfe43162" Issuer="http://windesheim.nl/adfs/services/trust/" IssueInstant="2015-06-10T08:21:45.097Z" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion">
                        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2015-06-10T08:21:45.082Z" NotOnOrAfter="2015-06-10T09:21:45.082Z">
                            <saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
                                <saml:Audience>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</saml:Audience>
                            </saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
                        </saml:Conditions>
                        <saml:AttributeStatement>
                            <saml:Subject>
                                <saml:NameIdentifier Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">[..]saml:NameIdentifier>
                                <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                                    <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
                                </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                            </saml:Subject>
                            <saml:Attribute AttributeName="UPN" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims">
                                <saml:AttributeValue>[username]</saml:AttributeValue>
                            </saml:Attribute>
                            <saml:Attribute AttributeName="ImmutableID" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveID/Federation/2008/05">
                                <saml:AttributeValue>[..]saml:AttributeValue>
                            </saml:Attribute>
                        </saml:AttributeStatement>
                        <saml:AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:password" AuthenticationInstant="2015-06-10T08:21:45.082Z">
                            <saml:Subject>
                                <saml:NameIdentifier Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">[..]</saml:NameIdentifier>
                                <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                                    <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
                                </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                            </saml:Subject>
                        </saml:AuthenticationStatement>
                        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                            <ds:SignedInfo>
                                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                                <ds:Reference URI="#_68133973-ed12-49d7-9f43-421bcfe43162">
                                    <ds:Transforms>
                                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                                    </ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                                    <ds:DigestValue[..]</ds:DigestValue>
                                </ds:Reference>
                            </ds:SignedInfo>
                            <ds:SignatureValue>[..]</ds:SignatureValue>
                            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                                <X509Data>[..]</X509Certificate>
                                </X509Data>
                            </KeyInfo>
                        </ds:Signature>
                    </saml:Assertion>
                </trust:RequestedSecurityToken>
                <trust:RequestedAttachedReference>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference k:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:k="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
                        <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID">[some_guid]</o:KeyIdentifier>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </trust:RequestedAttachedReference>
                <trust:RequestedUnattachedReference>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference k:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:k="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
                        <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID[some_guid]</o:KeyIdentifier>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </trust:RequestedUnattachedReference>
                <trust:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</trust:TokenType>
                <trust:RequestType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue</trust:RequestType>
                <trust:KeyType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
            </trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
        </trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

2. To Federated STS

Soap Request

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:0c1704ed-2ef3-4718-87fa-97734518b13f</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/RST2.srf</a:To>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2015-06-10T08:21:45.418Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2015-06-10T08:26:45.418Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
                                <saml:Assertion MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" AssertionID="_68133973-ed12-49d7-9f43-421bcfe43162" Issuer="http://windesheim.nl/adfs/services/trust/" IssueInstant="2015-06-10T08:21:45.097Z" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion">
                        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2015-06-10T08:21:45.082Z" NotOnOrAfter="2015-06-10T09:21:45.082Z">
                            <saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
                                <saml:Audience>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</saml:Audience>
                            </saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
                        </saml:Conditions>
                        <saml:AttributeStatement>
                            <saml:Subject>
                                <saml:NameIdentifier Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">[..]saml:NameIdentifier>
                                <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                                    <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
                                </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                            </saml:Subject>
                            <saml:Attribute AttributeName="UPN" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims">
                                <saml:AttributeValue>[username]</saml:AttributeValue>
                            </saml:Attribute>
                            <saml:Attribute AttributeName="ImmutableID" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveID/Federation/2008/05">
                                <saml:AttributeValue>[..]saml:AttributeValue>
                            </saml:Attribute>
                        </saml:AttributeStatement>
                        <saml:AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:password" AuthenticationInstant="2015-06-10T08:21:45.082Z">
                            <saml:Subject>
                                <saml:NameIdentifier Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">[..]</saml:NameIdentifier>
                                <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                                    <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
                                </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                            </saml:Subject>
                        </saml:AuthenticationStatement>
                        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                            <ds:SignedInfo>
                                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                                <ds:Reference URI="#_68133973-ed12-49d7-9f43-421bcfe43162">
                                    <ds:Transforms>
                                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                                    </ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                                    <ds:DigestValue[..]</ds:DigestValue>
                                </ds:Reference>
                            </ds:SignedInfo>
                            <ds:SignatureValue>[..]</ds:SignatureValue>
                            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                                <X509Data>[..]</X509Certificate>
                                </X509Data>
                            </KeyInfo>
                        </ds:Signature>
                    </saml:Assertion>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
            <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
                <a:EndpointReference>
                    <a:Address>urn:crmemea:dynamics.com</a:Address>
                </a:EndpointReference>
            </wsp:AppliesTo>
            <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
        </t:RequestSecurityToken>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

For future googlers, not exactly the OP:

I had created a SAML bearer token and was trying to exchange it for a JWT with ADFS.
Needed to set the `KeyType` property to avoid this error:

```
var binding = new IssuedTokenWSTrustBinding();
binding.SecurityMode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
binding.KeyType = SecurityKeyType.BearerKey;


// set up the ws-trust channel factory
var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, new EndpointAddress(options.AdfsIssuedTokenMixedEndpoint))
{
    TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13
};
```

Comment: Hello, could you please provide more information on `exchange SAML bearer token for a JWT with ADFS`? Thank you